# Java Swing: Transparent JFXPanel

Tags: java, swing, javafx, transparency

I want to use a transparent JFXPanel on top of an AWT Panel.

Before you ask, I really need to have a transparent JFXPanel in a Swing application as the final goal is to enrich an existing AWT application with draggable JavaFx windows.

Here is what I tried:

```
public class JavaFXTest {

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        // Java FX Panel
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
        Text text = new Text();
        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");
        root.setCenter(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.TRANSPARENT);
        fxPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
        fxPanel.setOpaque(false);

        // AWT Panel
        Button button = new Button("AWT Button");
        Label label = new Label("AWT Label");
        Panel awtPanel = new Panel();
        awtPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 300);
        awtPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        awtPanel.add(label);
        awtPanel.add(button);

        // Layered Pane
        JLayeredPane layers = new JLayeredPane();
        layers.add(fxPanel, 1);
        layers.add(awtPanel, 2);

        // Main Panel
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(layers, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Main Window        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to just have the text from the JFXPanel while still seeing the AWT elements, but as it is the JFXPanel background remains opaque.

Comment: First rule of Swing: don't mix AWT and Swing. When you add Java FX to this cocktail, you add the third level of headache.

Comment: Try using fxPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));